# ADO.Net query suddenly stopped working on my query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm using ADO.Net in an ASP.Net application.  All of a sudden my query stopped working.  This is the original query:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(this.connection))
{
    var sql = @"select *
                From Contacts.Departments a
                Left Outer Join Contacts.ContactMapping b on a.DepartmentID = b.DepartmentID
                Left Outer Join Contacts.Contacts c on b.ContactID = c.ContactID
                Left Outer Join Contacts.Divisions d on b.DivisionID = d.DivisionID
                Left Outer Join Contacts.Emails e on b.EmailID = e.EmailID
                Left Outer Join Contacts.Phones f on b.PhoneID = f.PhoneID
                Where a.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID and c.IsDeleted = 0 and b.IsDeleted = 0 and f.PhoneTypeID = 1;";
    ...

    ...
}
```

when it executes I get an error

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The results should only return 45 rows so its not very large. When I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, it's not an issue and I get the 45 rows.

But in my application if I put a top in the statement then it works:

```
var sql = @"select top 1000 *
            From Contacts.Departments a
            Left Outer Join Contacts.ContactMapping b on a.DepartmentID = b.DepartmentID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Contacts c on b.ContactID = c.ContactID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Divisions d on b.DivisionID = d.DivisionID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Emails e on b.EmailID = e.EmailID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Phones f on b.PhoneID = f.PhoneID
            Where a.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID and c.IsDeleted = 0 and b.IsDeleted = 0 and f.PhoneTypeID = 1;";
```

or if I take out the parameterized query and just add the value directly in the string:

```
var sql = $@"select *
            From Contacts.Departments a
            Left Outer Join Contacts.ContactMapping b on a.DepartmentID = b.DepartmentID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Contacts c on b.ContactID = c.ContactID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Divisions d on b.DivisionID = d.DivisionID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Emails e on b.EmailID = e.EmailID
            Left Outer Join Contacts.Phones f on b.PhoneID = f.PhoneID
            Where a.DepartmentID = {department_id} and c.IsDeleted = 0 and b.IsDeleted = 0 and f.PhoneTypeID = 1;";
```

This is so odd because I have not touched the code and suddenly it just failed.  When I test the same in my development machine I can recreate the error and solution above.

I'm kinda in a lose on what to check since, the query works when I modify it to the one of the two above.  But, then why would the original fail when trying to retrieve the data from SQL Server 2016

Comment: Could be a case of parameter sniffing. Try adding a hint to the end of the query, either `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`

Comment: I added to end like so "... f.PhoneTypeID = 1 OPTION(RECOMPILE);" and it worked.  So what causes this?

Comment: With the recompile hint, the query is optimized for the actual parameter values passed every time it's executed instead of reusing an existing plan that may be good for some values but bad for others. See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) for a thorough explanation. The article focusses on stored procedures but applies to parameterized queries in general.

Comment: Thanks for the info Dan I really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

check in your connection string the time out variable

example

Integrated Security = SSPI; **Connection Timeout = 30**

Comment: I tried that and it didn't worked.  Using Dan recommendation in using OPTION(RECOMPILE) worked.  But I'm not sure why?  Is this a change in SQL Server that the administrator did?